# Passing list from controller to view results in not finding any model/namespace in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my code:
Controller -

```
DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();
List<users> UsersToView = new List<users>();
UsersToView = db.users.ToList();

return View(UsersToView);
```

View -

I wrote this: `@model List<UsersToView>`
But this gives me an error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'UsersToView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And I'm not sure what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: @Div I've tried this `@model List<projectname.Models.users>` but I cannot get to the additional .UsersToView

Comment: @Div It is only in the controller

Comment: @Div is it a good way tho? I've read somewhere that it is not a bulletproof or something @_ @

Comment: No, it's not. create a model of `UsersToView` and bind it from controller and add that on view that its best practices

Comment: Or you can pass directly return `return View(db.users.ToList());` and on view page `@model List<User>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that the other answers may solve your problem, but let me add a quick description about the problem itself:

> I wrote this: `@model List<UsersToView>` But this gives me an error

The reason why you get an error at that line of code is because when you write `@model` the compiler expects that what follows next is a data type. So this way you are specifically declaring what data type should your model have. Although the declaration is correct, except the thing that `UsersToView` is not a type, but it is a local variable declared in controller, so the view can't even see it, and tries to interpret it as an unkown type in a `List<UsersToView>`. Basically what are you saying now is that your model is a list of unkown types.

This is why the compiler is saying:

> The type or namespace name 'UsersToView' could not be found

What you are supposed to do is declare the actual type of `UsersToView` in your model declaration, instead of the variable name, as stated in the other's answers:

```
@model IEnumerable<users>
```

So please remark that now it's used `users` instead of `UsersToView`. Of course I have written `IEnumerable` which is more generic than `List` so you can send an array of `users` too to the view, but if you need LINQ methods for `List`s then of course you can do:

```
@model List<users>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you can pass a list of `users` like this way:

Controller:

```
DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

return View(db.users.ToList());
```

And view:

```
@model IEnumerable<users>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller code looks good. Try with this code in View

**First Way**

```
@model IList<users>
```

**Second Way**

```
@model IEnumerable<users>
```